# Animation SplashScreen and Masking LinearLayout

Tags: android, animation, android-linearlayout

I want to make SplashScreen. Is it possible to reproduce [this](https://youtu.be/wX66UdSTdJo) with only animations? [Here](https://i.ibb.co/0mcCbLN/splash.png) is what I have done so far. I’ll deal with fade_in, fade_out animations, but I don’t know about masking the layout. Can I use a mask on LinearLayout?

Answer (score 0):

i can help you with it, i guess it can be done natively, but this is my first approach, and we can go from there:

1. as layout you need to have 2 recyclerviews with list of alphabets, one on the right and the other on the left with starting alpha 0.
2. when the activity starts you animate alpha of both recyclerviews from 0 to 1.
3. the part hiding that hides both recyclerview elements is a gradient background with colors going from purewhite #ffffff to full transparency #00ffffff
4. you have 2 views with gradient backgrounds mentioned above with opposite rotation angle, because of opposite directions (one from down to up, and the other from up to down).
5. prepare same adapter with the same list of alphabets from A to R and assign them to both recyclerviews, and set one to start at the index of A and the other at the index of R
6. now use smoothscroll on both recyclerview, one to scroll to the last element, and the other to scroll to the first element, and you can set the speed of smoothscrolling to be faster than usual if you felt it needed.
7. After finishing scrolling, get the adapter element at the selected position of the recyclerview and use an update listener with value animator and ArgbEvaluator from the black color to white and set text color to the current value of onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) animation.getAnimatedValue().
8. At the same time, use the same process as above to change the background color of the parent layout from the white color to black color.